# Restcomm variable for the date

Tags: restcomm

I'm creating a new App in RVD and creating a request to an external service. Everything works as expected, I'm using different variables as core_From, core_To and so on. The problem is, I would like also send the date when the call is done but I don't find any variable for that and I wasn't able to find any documentation defining those variables.

I guess I could invoke an external service to know the date, but it seems to costly to do something so trivial... so I think I'm missing something obvious here. Any help on that would be welcomed.

Comment: Anton, unfortunately RVD does not support this feature yet but you could work your way around it using ES as you suggested. There is a pending issue for adding date support though, so stay tuned.

Comment: here is the issue:
https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/issues/1034

Comment: Thanks @otsakir, if I have the opportunity, I will add the feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this [PR](https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/pull/1055), the variable core_callTimestamp is available to provide this functionality.